# How do I use Selenium to switch subpages in espncricket web

Tags: python, selenium

In this site's Ball by Ball commentary, there are two countries, AUS and HI, and I would now like to set up a program to select AUS, but when aus has no class name and xpath dosen't work, how to solve this problems.

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 

web="https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/carlton-series-2000-01-61080/australia-vs-west-indies-1st-match-65601/ball-by-ball-commentary"

driver.get(web)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".dropdown-container").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='main-container']/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/button/span").click()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7Ye0.png)

Comment: ok,this is the fist time i use overflow, I don't know how to give credit, i am still exploreing

Comment: now regarding your question, what exactly you wanna do ? I see there's a drop down with AUS and WI

Comment: First, I drop down with AUS and WI, I want to select the aus label and click it ,but I have try different ways, I cannot foucus this label bying using selenium label, do you have some good ideas? Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question then you want to select either one of the country from drop down. **PS :-** check the comments for better understanding.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/carlton-series-2000-01-61080/australia-vs-west-indies-1st-match-65601/ball-by-ball-commentary")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class$='comment-inning-dropdown']"))).click()

# to select first team (without name, cause in future you can have different country name)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ci-dd__menu li:nth-of-type(1)"))).click()

# to select second team (without name, cause in future you can have different country name)
#wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ci-dd__menu li:nth-of-type(2)"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```